# Printing receipts in thermal printer from web browser

Tags: html, printing

I have made a PHP billing application and everything is cool. But now I want to print the bill in a thermal printer. I am just wondering how to set the height of the bill dynamically according to content of the bill, Which means, when I have fewer items, the page should be smaller and when I have long list of items, the page should grow accordingly. But now while I print I get lot of empty spaces in the bill at the bottom. I mean the printer prints out more empty space even after the bill content is over.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: show effort and code.

Comment: Sorry... But no code for this. We just give ctrl+P from a page and try printing the page.